# What is the reasoning for this soldier in Forrest Gump being surrounded by a plastic bubble?

Tags: analysis, forrest-gump

I was watching Forrest Gump, and during the scene where Forrest goes to tell Lt. Dan about being awarded the Medal of Honor, I noticed that a soldier in the background was surrounded by a plastic bubble in the hospital as seen below:

[image: Plastic bubble]

Why was the soldier surrounded by this plastic shield? Was this something actually done during the Vietnam War or just a movie prop?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The plastic bubble is an **isolation chamber: it prevents the spread of airborne disease and contaminants.** Isolation prevents the spread of contaminants both from the patient to the outside, and from the outside to the patient inside.

A machine attached by a tube filters the air entering and leaving the chamber.

Presumably, the soldier inside has contracted a contagious disease in the jungle and is being quarantined to avoid spreading it to others.

[image: Hospital isolation chamber]

Comment: More likely to be burns.  Makeshift tents like those were erected around burn victims to try and prevent infection.

Comment: @Tim: if that's true, you should write a separate answer (with sources/images, if possible)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: Tim's suggestion (which I agree with) doesn't change the fact that this is a makeshift isolation chamber. The distinction between this answer and Tim's suggested answer (**why** the tent is used) is not obvious from the movie, and therefore mostly opinion based. This answer gets the facts straight, and makes a fair assumption. Tim added another possible assumption, but did not counter any of the facts.

Comment: @Rahul: You provide no evidence as to why _this specific soldier_ is in an isolation chamber because of Agent Orange. Which leads us back to my initial statement, the reason why this particular soldier was in isolation is not clear and opinion-based. The usage of flamethrowers and napalm during the Vietnam war makes burns an equally likely possibility, as does general infectiousness (due to soldiers being in a climate they're not used to).

Comment: @Flater: I have added a part in the end from First Blood. Some were exposed to it some were not. To avoid contamination to other soldiers they were kept in isolation. I hope this answers your question. Thanks for pointing out again. I will now add it to answer.

Comment: @Rahul: ["contamination"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/contamination) is not the same as ["contagion"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/contagion). Agent Orange is a contaminant, but its negative health effects are slow-acting (though of course severe) and **not contagious** (from person to person). Your own quote talks about someone getting cancer. Cancer is not contagious.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65406/discussion-between-rahul-and-flater).

Comment: My first thought was that it was an oxygen tent, but isolation makes more sense.  Oxygen tents are typically smaller .